# Calculate left css value for skewed div

Tags: javascript, css, math, skew

I have a wiper div which I want to use to wipe diagonally through a parent div.
The wiper div has the following class:

```
.wiper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

I want the wiper to start offscreen to the right, and end offscreen to the left.
When the wiper is halfways, the screen must be completely filled by the wiper.

The problem is, I don't know how big the wipers parent is. So I need to calculate the following:

**Width:** How wide in percent must the wiper be, to fill the screen when it is halfway.

**Startleft:** What should the starting left property be in percent, for the wiper to be just offscreen right.

**Endleft:** What should the ending left property be, for the wiper to be just offscreen left.

Here is an example in jsfiddle, but with hardcoded values. I just don't know how to calculate the relative values, when dealing with a skewed div.

http://jsfiddle.net/jpg850kx/22/

Comment: Isn't that just *math*?

Comment: Ask **[Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)** - I'm sure he can help.

Comment: you need to know basic maths first

Comment: I guess I asked the question in the wrong place then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something differently using gradient where you don't need complex calculation:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.wiper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200%;
  width: 400%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index:1;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,orange 49.5%,transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(to top right,orange 49.5%,transparent 50%);
  background-size:50.1% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:left,right;
  transition:all 3s;
}
#wrapper:hover .wiper{
  left:-300%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    Old content
  </div>

  <div class="wiper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a nice alternative way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Temani! You're not using anti-aliasing trick-values for the gradient? (I can see it even if it moves :))

Comment: @TakitIsy yes right, am expecting that the transition will be fast ;) .. edited anyway ;)

Comment: I got this working. Thank you. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpg850kx/44/